# Why are BEGIN and END optional for SQL procedures and aren't optional for functions?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, syntax

I'm learning about SQL Server stored procedures and functions and I got surprised when I saw that you don't need to use BEGIN and END when there are multiple statements on it. It seems strange to not have a clear end for the definition, what if I forget GO before writing a SELECT below it, for instance, or writing an EXEC for it, making it recursive with infinite loop?

Functions with multiple statements need to have BEGIN/END, of course it would be ugly and unsave to have a RETURN without an explicit block of code, but is it the only reason for this difference? Is writing a procedure in the same file with other things, such SELECT, so bad that it isn't expected?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Well, I'd say that because a function needs to be executed as a single statement, it needs BEGIN/END whereas a procedure does not need it, unless it needs to be executed as a single statement.

Comment: Get in the habit of using `BEGIN`/`END` (or, when you are more advanced, `BEGIN CATCH`/`END TRY`.  Programming languages often have ways of doing things that are not good ideas; that doesn't mean that you are obligated to use them.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of T-SQL. Unfortunately, the language is quite abnormal, having evolved over the years and consistency seems to have been right at the back of the minds of those who designed some of the features. The best you can do is sigh and accept it.